# iOS Swift passing variables between viewControllers using Segue

Tags: ios, iphone, view, swift, segue

I am trying to understand how to pass variables between two views in a iOS application. My main aim is learn this so I can use it in my own project (a tip calculator). The code I wrote is at the following github link:

http://bit.ly/1mVra4l

I did everything as described in following tutorial:
http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/

I am running into two problems:

1) When I run the app and click on the button, a breakpoint automatically triggers at the line

```
       var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as secondViewController;
```

I am pretty sure I did not set any breakpoints anywhere.

2) When I press continue in lldb, I get the crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) at the same line.

This problem is driving me nuts. Any help will be appreciated.

I am using xcode6-beta6, Swift language

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your code. Its throwing error  **Unknown class secondViewController in Interface Builder** . Even though you have given the right name in the interface builder it is not recognising it due to some reason(probably a beta issue). You can just remove the `Class name` of secondViewController in IB and add it again, let it autocomplete it. It will works

Comment: Thanks. That works. I have been ignoring the error as I read elsewhere that it doesn't do anything bad. Looks like I was wrong.

Comment: this is retarded but fixed the issue, even though its out of beta now